# need css to allow user to mark as read a single post in a digest

Tags: html, css, html-email

I email to my list an HTML digest of 20 or so posts. A list-member asked for the ability to mark as read individual posts within the digest. I came up with a nifty way to do that, which works locally (using Chrome to read the local .HTM file I produce) but which doesn't work on any of the 4 email clients I've tested.

The idea is to include a white, and therefore invisible, check mark next to each post. Then I make a link "Mark this post as read" that goes to an achor  tag somewhere in the post. Then that makes the "site" have the status of "visited" and my a:visited rule specifies a visible color (the same color as for unvisited links) and I use !important to override the "white" color. So the check mark is seen only if one has clicked on: Mark this post as read.

The whole thing is something like this:

```
In <style>:
a { color: #2020b7; }
a:visited { color: #2020b7 !important }

In <body>:
<a name="post-1"></a>
<a href="#post-1" style="color: #ffffff;">&#10004;</a>  <== check mark
<a href="#post-1">Mark this post as read</a>
```

That's a reconstruction, typed in here, so there may be typos. It works fine locally. But neither Outlook 2010, Eudora 7, Gmail or Yahoo mail seem to be accepting the anchor links or playing ball at all with this code.

Answer (score 2):

that is a clever idea!

**Ultimately we'll be handcuffed by email clients' lack of support for `:visited` link states,** which may explain why you're not seeing this work in some email clients.

[image]
[source](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

---

**CSS in `<style>`:**

```
a:visited,
a:visited .checkmark {
    color: #2020b7 !important;
}
```

**HTML in  `<body>`:**

```
<a name="post-1" style="color: #2020b7;">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;" class="checkmark">&#10004;</a>  /* check mark */
    Mark this post as read
</a>
```

---

Another way you could approach this is by hiding the checkbox

**CSS in `<style>`:**

```
a:visited .checkmark {
    display:inline !important;
    font-size:10px !important;
    color:#2020b7 !important;
    line-height:10px !important;
    max-height:auto !important;
    max-width:auto !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
    mso-hide:none !important;
}
```

**HTML in  `<body>`:**

```
<a name="post-1" style="color: #2020b7;">
    <span style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#{color};line-height:1px;font-family:{font};max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all; class="checkmark">&#10004;</a>  /* check mark */
    Mark this post as read
</a>
```

But this example also depends on support for the `:visited` link state.

Comment: I copied and pasted both sets of code and tested. Neither worked. The "Mark this post as read" wasn't even active--just text. Wasn't there supposed to be an "a href" in there?! I've seen people complaining about Outlook turning visited links purple. My problem (Outlook 2010) is that it doesn't respond to visiting at all. By the way, since Outlook strips out style in the head, I also tried pasting it into a section that has the "if (gte mso 9)|(IE)" thingy. Didn't help.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger Yea, I'm not sure there's a way to make this work. [Outlook **does not** strip out the `<head>`](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) but has (as you say) spotty to no support for `:visited`. I _believe_ Outlook turning links purple is a application stylesheet rather than one that's set by the email markup, but could be wrong about that.

Comment: Then I'll have to accomplish this by using some element that does something when a user clicks on it, in all email clients. The only one I can think of is a href jump to somewhere. So I'll see if I can think of a way to get that to put (or make visible) a check mark next to a post.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve it **BUT** I realized the user can accomplish all this, and more, himself: he need only hit Reply and mark up the Reply draft as he likes, even adding comments. When he's finished with it, he can either discard the draft or send it to himself.